# App unfortunately closing

Tags: android-studio

I am receiving "App has unfortunately stopped" error. I am using parse so I am assuming the issue lies somewhere within that.

This is the java file that I causes the error when loading

```
public class NewTipActivity extends Activity {

private Tip tip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   tip = new Tip();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //New Tip Fragment
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_tip);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new NewTipFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}

public Tip getCurrentTip() {
    return tip;
}
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette/com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.NewTipActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user
>   with null id
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id
>        at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308)
>        at com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:61)
>        at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3385)
>        at com.parse.ParseObject.(ParseObject.java:181)
>        at com.parse.ParseObject.(ParseObject.java:127)
>        at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Tip.(Tip.java:17)
>        at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.NewTipActivity.onCreate(NewTipActivity.java:20)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I may have figured it out, the API im using on my phone might be to low. But i am not sure

Comment: Some relevant code may be helpful. Especially the lines your stacktrace points to.

Comment: I am trying to add more code, but I do not understand how to use this website yet. So I am having a hard time copying my error log and even code onto the question. It's becoming a bit frustrating.

Comment: Takes some time and practice to get used to, but don't give up, it's worth it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [App unfortunately stops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648622/app-unfortunately-stops)