# App unfortunately stops

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am receiving "App has unfortunately stopped" error. I am using parse so I am assuming the issue lies somewhere within that.

This is the java file that I causes the error when i try loading it

```
public class NewTipActivity extends Activity {

private Tip tip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   tip = new Tip();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //New Tip Fragment
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_tip);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new NewTipFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}

public Tip getCurrentTip() {
    return tip;
}
}
```

This is the logCat 
Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user
>   with null id at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308) at
>   com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:61) at
>   com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3385) at

Tip class (This is where the getAuthor() needs to be declared) but I am having a serious block and can't figure this out.

package com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette;

```
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.ParseFile;



    @ParseClassName ("Tip")
    public class Tip extends ParseObject {


        public Tip(){
           // a default constructor is required
        }

        public String getTitle() { return getString("title"); }

        public void setTitle(String title) { put("title", title); }

        public ParseUser getAuthor() { return getParseUser("Author");}

        public void setAuthor(ParseUser user) { put("Author", user);}

        public String getRating(){return getString("rating");}

        public void setRating(String rating) { put("rating" , rating);}

}
```

Comment: What does your Tip class look like?

Comment: I will upload the tip class now.. There is an error here, I need to call getAuthor() but I am having trouble using parse still. I will post it now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308)

User has a null id.

> com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Tip.(Tip.java:17) at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.NewTipActivity.onCreate(NewTipActivity.java:20)

Those are the lines where you're having your issue. Please avoid posting broad questions like this. For details on what makes a good and bad question on SO, [check out the official SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically,

> Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

and, relating to titles:

> If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, write the title last
>   - sometimes writing the rest of the question first can make it easier to describe the problem.
>
> Examples:
>
> Bad: C# Math Confusion
>
> Good: Why does using float instead of int give
>   me different results when all of my inputs are integers?
>
> Bad: [php]
>   session doubt
>
> Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based
>   on session data in PHP?
>
> Bad: android if else problems
>
> Good: Why does
>   str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still getting use to android development and this website. I am going to post my tip class in order to receive a little more guidance on this issue.